# How to add execution time taken for an API to respond in Lumen framework in the JSON response

Tags: laravel, lumen

I would like to add the time taken by the API to respond in the response JSON. Currently developing API with Lumen framework.

If anyone can guide with best approach. Not sure if I would have to use any Hooks provided by framework, or just calculate them in routes file. And how to push it to all the API responses.

PS: Still learning Laravel/Lumen framework.

Thanks,
Tanmay

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your `public/index.php` file, add a constant there:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Create The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| First we need to get an application instance. This creates an instance
| of the application / container and bootstraps the application so it
| is ready to receive HTTP / Console requests from the environment.
|
*/

// To calculate your app execution time
define('LUMEN_START', microtime(true));

$app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$app->run();
```

The next step is create a middleware and enable it so we can manipulate our response. Create a middleware in `app/Http/Middleware` with name `MeasureExecutionTime.php`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class MeasureExecutionTime
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure                 $next
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Get the response
        $response = $next($request);

        // Calculate execution time
        $executionTime = microtime() - LUMEN_START;

        // I assume you're using valid json in your responses
        // Then I manipulate them below
        $content = json_decode($response->getContent(), true) + [
            'execution_time' => $executionTime,
        ];

        // Change the content of your response
        $response->setContent($content);

        // Return the response
        return $response;
    }
}
```

To enable this middleware in your application, add:

```
$app->middleware([
   App\Http\Middleware\MeasureExecutionTime::class
]);
```

In your `bootstrap/app.php` file. So it would be like this:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

try {
    (new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__.'/../'))->load();
} catch (Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException $e) {
    // n00p
}

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Create The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here we will load the environment and create the application instance
| that serves as the central piece of this framework. We'll use this
| application as an "IoC" container and router for this framework.
|
*/

$app = new Laravel\Lumen\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);

// $app->withFacades();

// $app->withEloquent();

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Container Bindings
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Now we will register a few bindings in the service container. We will
| register the exception handler and the console kernel. You may add
| your own bindings here if you like or you can make another file.
|
*/

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
    App\Console\Kernel::class
);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Middleware
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, we will register the middleware with the application. These can
| be global middleware that run before and after each request into a
| route or middleware that'll be assigned to some specific routes.
|
*/

$app->middleware([
   App\Http\Middleware\MeasureExecutionTime::class
]);

// $app->middleware([
//    App\Http\Middleware\ExampleMiddleware::class
// ]);

// $app->routeMiddleware([
//     'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
// ]);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Service Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here we will register all of the application's service providers which
| are used to bind services into the container. Service providers are
| totally optional, so you are not required to uncomment this line.
|
*/

// $app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
// $app->register(App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class);
// $app->register(App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Load The Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next we will include the routes file so that they can all be added to
| the application. This will provide all of the URLs the application
| can respond to, as well as the controllers that may handle them.
|
*/

$app->group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function ($app) {
    require __DIR__.'/../app/Http/routes.php';
});

return $app;
```

> **Note If there are another middlewares in your application, you may add `MeasureExecutionTime` middleware at the `END` of any other middlewares.**

For further research I give you a link to documentation:

1. [Middleware](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware).
2. [Responses](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses).

---

## UPDATE

If you don't want to add elapsed time to your response body, you can add it to the headers:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class MeasureExecutionTime
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        $response->headers->set('X-Elapsed-Time', microtime(true) - LUMEN_START);

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: One note:  you sould add the response time as a header like X-Response-Time. This way you save time by not decoding and encoding your response. Also it works also for other types of content: images, html,etc

Comment: @krisanalfa There need two corrections. 1.`$executionTime = microtime(true) - LUMEN_START;`2.`$response->setContent(json_encode($content));`

Answer (score 3):

In directory `public` you have file `index.php`. Create there a variable:

```
define('LUMEN_START', microtime());
```

Now in your controller, you can just pass a parameter:

```
return [
    'response_time' => microtime() - LUMEN_START
];
```

It will be measuring time from start (`public/index.php` is the first file run by server) to the response.

Comment: We should add `'response_time' => microtime() - LUMEN_START` in each response / controller. I prefer using `Middleware` as global solution. Please read my answer below.

Comment: for simplicity this is good, but probably will go with Middleware solution so i don't have to add separately for each response.

Answer (score 0):

I use Lumen 5.3 and want to return `JsonResponse`. Because of this I had to modify the middleware solution from Alfa a little bit:

Instead of

```
// Change the content of your response
$response->setContent($content);
```

I use

```
// Change the content of your response
$response->setData($content);
```

Not sure if this is related to `JsonResponse` or the Laravel/Lumen version but it works for me.